# Suma de dos columnas de dos tablas diferentes

Tags: mysql

estoy aqui para que por favor me ayuden con este problema para resolver.
Tengo dos tablas en Mysql  llamadas:

```
| Factura  |
|----------|
|Idfactura |
|Total     |

|Pago_factura  |
|--------------|
|Idpago        |
|Idfactura     |
|Pago          |
```

Tengo esta consulta para unir ambar tablas:

```
Select sum(Pago),  sum(Total),  (sum(pago) - sum(total)) as pendiente from Pago_factura
Left join factura on factura.idfactura = pago.idfactura
Group by pago_factura.idfactura
```

El problema está en que, por ejemplo, si tengo una `factura` x con un total 5000 y tengo dos pagos a esa factura x de la tabla `pago_factura`, el tal de la tabla factura se duplica osea un total 10000.
Por eso le estoy escribiendo para que por favor ayudarme con este problema.

Comment: Debes incluir  la columna **total** o bien usar FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: Si es como dices la factura debe ser centro de la consulta. Pero como quiera sigue duplicando de la forma que dices yo agrupado los totales y idfactura.  Y es que yo sago el tal de todas las facturas y de todos los pagos, porque son total general

Answer (score 2):

Es que `total` debe formar parte del `group by`

```
Select ifnull(sum(p.Pago),0),  
       f.Total,  
       ifnull(sum(p.Pago),0) - f.total as pendiente 
       from factura f
       Left join Pago_factura p
            on f.idfactura = p.idfactura
       Group by f.idfactura, f.Total
```

Me permito sugerirte otros cambios:

- Invierto el orden de las tablas, para que la consulta nos retorne siempre las facturas, tengan o no pagos, (entiendo por el `left join` que usas que esa debiera es la idea)
- Agrego un `ifnull(sum(pagos),0)` para evitar `NULL` el `0` es más claro
- Alias de tabla